# I wanted to learn the exact steps along with mantras to do nitya agni at home

Tags: sandhyavandanam, agni, homam

I wanted to learn the exact steps along with mantras to do nitya agni at home. I have attained dwija. I wanted to know about all the yagnas like brahma yagya etc. The detailed steps. Could anyone post them.
Thanks in advance for your response.